# How to draw a lot of 3D lines in Unreal Engine efficiently? (>10k)

Tags: drawing, line, unreal-engine4

So I have a project with a lot of data points that are tracked through time, around 10k. What I really want to do is draw a line through each data track. However, everything I have tried seems to really tank performance. I'm really not sure where to start with something this big. My first guess would be spline meshes but, I don't think it would be performant enough.

I've also dabbled a little bit with procedural meshes but, haven't been able to get too far with that either.

My next guess would be something in Niagara as that is how I am drawing the dots currently but, since ribbons can't be drawn on the GPU they aren't good option either. Maybe there is something like a line sprite that I can utilize? I'm not really sure.

I believe there is a way to maybe draw lines similar to that of debug lines which I think might work but, I don't really have a clue where to start on that one.

If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction or have already done something similar I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I think your idea with Niagara and line sprites is a solid approach. Make a unit sprite, place it on the halfway point between two data points, and scale it on one axis based on the distance. It may also be feasible with Niagara meshes instead. You will have to check which one is more performant.